# Смена имени дополнительного поля в 1с

Tags: 1с

Добрый день! Решаю одну малоизвестную для меня задачу в 1с (так как с ним не дружу). Задача значит такая у меня для разных категорий товаров в разделе Номенклатура задать дополнительные поля. Нашел на эту тему интересную статью, которая мне помогла создать такие поля, вот [ссылка](http://www.meteor-it.ru/articles/rabota-so-svoistvami-atributami-tovarov/).

Создал поля, при экспорте данных в xml (в файле import.xml) получил такую структуру:

```
<Товар>
                <Ид>eba4ed3e-a064-11e3-9402-0022151b9b35</Ид>
                <Штрихкод>2000000006369</Штрихкод>
                <Артикул>Проба артикула</Артикул>
                <Наименование>доставка 400</Наименование>
                <БазоваяЕдиница Код="796 " НаименованиеПолное="Штука" МеждународноеСокращение="PCE">шт</БазоваяЕдиница>
                <Группы>
                    <Ид>e7b53248-9d1d-11e3-bc68-b76af44bec11</Ид>
                </Группы>
                <ЗначенияСвойств>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <Ид>cbc05766-6a2d-11e4-9cb6-d850e63f3cf1</Ид>
                    <Значение>пурпурный</Значение>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <Ид>f00846c9-9d21-11e3-bc68-b76af44bec11</Ид>
                <Значение>122cf027-574c-11e3-9e52-0022151b9b35</Значение>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                </ЗначенияСвойств>
                <СтавкиНалогов>
                    <СтавкаНалога>
                        <Наименование>НДС</Наименование>
                        <Ставка>18</Ставка>
                    </СтавкаНалога>
                </СтавкиНалогов>
                <ЗначенияРеквизитов>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>ВидНоменклатуры</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Товар (пр. ТМЦ)</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>ТипНоменклатуры</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Товар</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>Код</Наименование>
                        <Значение>00-00007744</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>Полное наименование</Наименование>
                        <Значение>доставка 400</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                </ЗначенияРеквизитов>
            </Товар>
```

Значение с cbc05766-6a2d-11e4-9cb6-d850e63f3cf1 создал я. Вопрос такой как можно переименовать такие поля в человеческий язык, как например "Цвет товара", "Дата срока годности" и т.д? Чтобы не было таких страшных названий cbc05766-6a2d-11e4-9cb6-d850e63f3cf1... Или как добавить указание еще тега Наименование, к примеру так:

```
<ЗначенияСвойств>
          <ЗначенияСвойства>
            <Наименование>Количество скрепок</Наименование>
            <Значение>35</Значение>
          </ЗначенияСвойства>
```

1с программисты выручайте), нужна ваша помощь.

Comment: копайте в сторону настройки экспорта)

Comment: Ладно спасибо всем за ответы, сам разобрался).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ТекущийГУИД = НовыйУникальныйИдентификатор("cbc05766-6a2d-11e4-9cb6-d850e63f3cf1");

ТекСсылка = Справочники.Номенклатура.ПолучитьСсылку(ТекущийГУИД);

Имя = ТекСсылка.Наименование;

Comment: Мне надо в экспорте чтобы появилось поле  <Наименование>Количество скрепок</Наименование>. Я так понимаю надо поправить код в экспорте,чтобы формировался тег, где шло бы присвоение значения ТекСсылка.Наименование